# Why does false && (false)?false:true return true

Tags: java, syntax, ternary-operator

Please don't look at the condition as they are here to ease the understanding of the behavior

Why does result equals true ?

```
boolean result = false && (false)?false:true;
```

I know we can solve the issue doing:

```
boolean result = false && (false?false:true);
```

But I am just wondering why the first syntax is incorrect, looks like the '?' operator has more priority over '&&'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The *ternary conditional* ( `?:` ) has lower [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `&&`**. So

```
boolean result = false && (false)?false:true;
```

(having unnecessary parentheses); is equivalent to

```
boolean result = (false && false) ? false : true;
```

Since (since `false && false` is `false`), this reduces to

```
boolean result = false ? false : true;
```

which, of course, is `true`.

Answer (score 12):

1. && (logical AND)

Description :- Compares two expressions and returns true only if both evaluate to true. Returns false if one or both evaluate to false.

The following list shows all possible combinations:

```
true && false = false // Evaluates false because the second is false
false && true = false // Evaluates false because the first is false
true && true = true // Evaluates true because both are true
false && false = false// Evaluates false because both are false
```

Syntax

expression1 && expression2

[Cllick here to know more About Logical AND](https://www.processing.org/reference/logicalAND.html)

2. || (logical OR)

Description :- Compares two expressions and returns true if one or both evaluate to true. Returns false only if both expressions are false.

The following list shows all possible combinations:

```
true || false = true // Evaluates true because the first is true
false || true = true // Evaluates true because the second is true
true || true = true // Evaluates true because both are true
false || false = false // Evaluates false because both are false
```

Syntax

expression1 || expression2

[Click here to know about Logical OR](https://www.processing.org/reference/logicalOR.html)

Comment: You appear to have a copy paste error in your first set of examples. I believe it should be:  
`false && false // Evaluates false because neither are true` instead of your duplicate second row.

Answer (score 6):

`false && (false)` evaluates to `false`, so the last value of the ternary operator is returned, which is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
boolean result = false && (false)?false:true;
```

is interpreted as

```
boolean result = (false && (false))?false:true;
```

See: [Java operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). In the table you can see `&&` has higher precedence than `? :`.

Answer (score 1):

it is just some [boolean algegra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

```
False && false = true
false && true = false
true && true = true
true && false = false
```

So in the first case, it is like writting :

```
if (false && false){
result = false
} else {
result = true
}
```

In your second case, it is like writting :

```
result = false && (false == false);
```

and false == false returns true. So false && true returns false

Comment: My question is more about syntax than boolean algebra

Comment: @Leviathan56 `False && false != true`